# Decision behind closing duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

According to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), the duplicate questions may be closed. But some questions with same ground exist and they are not closed. For example, I noticed the following three questions of [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) are on the same topic - they are trying to customize the Drupal registration as multi-steps form:

- [How to customize registration process in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49582/how-to-customize-registration-process-in-drupal-7/)
- [Is there a way to add profile2 forms in multistep registration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48411/is-there-a-way-to-add-profile2-forms-in-multistep-registration)
- [how to add fields for drupal registration form internally souce code of drupal7.17 application](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56376/how-to-add-fields-for-drupal-registration-form-internally-souce-code-of-drupal7#comment59568_56376)

After reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), I realized that askers should research first and search the same topics before asking a question, but the above questions seems not acting like that.

I could flag one of them as exact duplicate, but my flag may be declined. I have experienced this.
Thus, what would be a good decision before I flag to close a question as exact duplicate?

Comment: [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag (or vote) away.

The most likely explanation is that these questions have just slipped through the net and not enough people have realised that they are duplicates.

A **lot** of questions get asked on Stack Overflow every hour (let alone day) so it's not surprising that things like this happen.

Answer (score 2):

To add to existing answer, **having some existing unclosed questions that are not following the faq rules doesn't mean questions like that are allowed** (and won't be closed). Stackoverflow is a community of like minded people, and there is every chance that one or two questions might slip under.

> *I could flag one of them as exact duplicate, but my flag may be declined. I have experienced this*

Also don't be discouraged if community does not agree with your flag. You make sure you do your thing as per rule, people here eventually will do the right thing for the site.

You should definitely flag away, if you thing the questions are duplicate.